# Live App Image & Description

Tags: quip, liveapps

Is there a way to set an image and description for a live app that I've published? Right now live apps seem to have a very generic image in the Apps & Templates modal, and absolutely no description. Is there a way to provide these images in the manifest so that Live Apps can feel as rich as the Quip-provided apps?

It seems the `@Q Partners` live app has somehow set an image, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

In manifest.json, include the key "thumbnail" and "description"

```
    "thumbnail": "icons/thumbnail.svg",
    "description": "my great app"
```

Comment: You can also point to a "toolbar" icon for a small (displayed at 16x16) svg to show in the app menu and autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can specify a 18x18 pixels SVG icon in your manifest.json file:
"toolbar_icon": "icons/toolbar.svg",